# EclipseLink MapKey composite unique keys

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

How to give composite unique keys ( address1 and address2) as Map key. Like  @MapKey(name = "address1", name = "address2")  instead of single unique key @MapKey(name = "address1").

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    @MapKey(name = "address1") 
    public Map<String, Address> getAddressMap() {
        return addressMap;
    }

}



@Entity
public class Address {
    private Integer id;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private Person person;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Embeddable type.

Create an embeddable class (i.e. `PersonAddress`) to encapsulate your `address1` and `address2` properties. Then use that embeddable class as a Map key.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    public Map<PersonAddress, Address> getAddressMap() {
        return addressMap;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Address {
    private Integer id;

    @Embedded
    private PersonAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonAddress {
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
}
```